# gulp command not recognized in Jenkins

Tags: node.js, jenkins, gulp

I've installed gulp and it works well in my cmd. So when I'm trying the gulp commands they work well. So I'm going to this path in my cmd:

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Jenkins\workspace\project1
```

And I can run gulp (its a github project on my Jenkins).
But when I'm working on my project1 in Jenkins itself (localhost), the gulp commands aren't recognized. Jenkins doesn't know gulp.

How do I have to integrate gulp in Jenkins? So my Jenkins will know its commands. I read something about node.js and its pluging.
I also read something about a frontend-maven-plugin/
 but it isn't clear at all.

Comment: Does the Jenkins-User have the gulp-binary in its PATH?

Comment: No, is it this path?: C:\Users\username\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\gulp
And where do you have to put it?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You need to add the gulp path for Jenkins so it knows where the command resides.

> Manage Jenkins-->Configure System-->Global Properties:
>   [image]

Answer (score 4):

If you have gulp defined as your project's dependency then you can also use it directly:

`node_modules\.bin\gulp mytask`

Comment: You have to use something like the following as what you have provided above will not work:

    node node_modules\gulp\bin\gulp.js mytask